# I want to Embed an API call in my Website using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am using Kimonolabs and I want to Embed in my html the result of this JSON structure using jquery and I am new in jquery and javascript, so I did everything given in this tutorial : [Tutorial Kimonolabs](https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/204030650-Tutorial-Embed-Kimono-data-on-your-site-with-HTML-CSS-and-jQuery)

```
{
  "name": "CCF blog",
  "count": 104,
  "frequency": "Weekly",
  "version": 1,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "nextrun": "Tue May 12 2015 19:54:32 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionrun": "Tue May 05 2015 19:54:32 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection2": [
      {
        "Date": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=42",
          "text": "April 6, 2015"
        },
        "Titre": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=42",
          "text": "Le chemin vers la Responsabilité Sociétale des entreprises"
        },
        "description": "Qu’est-ce que c’est une entreprise RSE ? Est-ce une démarche réservée aux grandes entreprises ? Quels sont les enjeux réels ? Quel est l’état d’esprit ?"
      },
      {
        "Date": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=30",
          "text": "March 20, 2015"
        },
        "Titre": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=30",
          "text": "Formation continue … quel choix pour quel besoin professionnel ?"
        },
        "description": "Chacun d’entre nous suit, au cours de sa jeunesse une formation initiale jusqu’au statut universitaire pour s’engager dans le vie active, pourtant, il ne nous tarde de nous poser des questions sur les nouveaux besoins en formation selon nos enjeux professionnelles et notre motivation, soit pour nous convertir, booster notre carrière ou simplement renforcer nos connaissances et compétences."
      },
      {
        "Date": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=9",
          "text": "March 19, 2015"
        },
        "Titre": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=9",
          "text": "La TPE/ PME marocaine et le mangement par les processus"
        },
        "description": "Toute entreprise qu’elle soit cliente ou fournisseur a eu recours aux processus. Le management par le processus peut être un choix interne ou dicté par l’environnement externe, cas des clients qui exigent de leurs fournisseurs la mise en place de procédures spécifiques et la tenue d’un registre dédié, justifiant leurs applications."
      },
      {
        "Date": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=1",
          "text": "March 19, 2015"
        },
        "Titre": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=1",
          "text": "Coacher avec éthique … n’est-ce pas un vrai axe de différentiation ?"
        },
        "description": "Dès le début des années 2000, la relation de coaching n’apparait plus comme un effet de mode mais comme une pratique en progression, une pratique de plus en plus perçue comme un levier de développement, plutôt qu’une simple aide en cas de difficulté ;"
      }
    ],
```

I use this jquery Script with a proper html/css structure (foundation) "titre-article". It is my html class and I want to update:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
  url:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api//////?apikey=////////////",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (response) {
  //Do something with the response
  var collection = response.results.collection2;

  $(".titre-article").html(collection.Titre.text);


  },
  error: function (xhr, status) {
    //handle errors
  }
});
</script>
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you see any error in console? And response of AJAX in Network tab.

Comment: Yes this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined in this line : $(".titre-article").html(collection.Titre.text);

Comment: There might not be text available inside `collection.Titre`. Check your object by logging it in console and update your code accordingly.

Comment: In my Json  "results": {
    "collection2": [
      {
        "Date": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=42",
          "text": "April 6, 2015"
        },
        "Titre": {
          "href": "http://ccf.ma/blog/?p=42",
          "text": "Le chemin vers la Responsabilité Sociétale des entreprises"
        },
        "description": "Qu’est-ce que c’est une entreprise RSE ? Est-ce une démarche réservée aux grandes entreprises ? Quels sont les enjeux réels ? Quel est l’état d’esprit ?"
      },   There is the text object why cant i Call it then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is how you can get results

var collection = response.results.collection2[0];

$(".titre-article").html(collection.Titre.text);
```

Comment: i guess i can do it both ways ? $(".titre-article").html(collection[0].Titre.text);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `response.results.collection2` is an array but you are using as a object, you need to an index to access the values in the array

change `$(".titre-article").html(collection.Titre.text);` to `$(".titre-article").html(collection[0].Titre.text);`

This will give you the first element in the array

Comment: and if i want to show the second Title in a second DIV do i need to change it that way ? : $(".newdiv").html(collection[0].Titre[1].text);

Comment: You would you need to use $(".newdiv").html(collection[1].Titre.text)

Comment: One last Thing and if its not too much trouvle for you i tried to link the Title with my href property doing this but its not working :

 $(".newdiv").html(collection[1].Titre.text.href)

I want to show The title with a link behind

Comment: You can use $(".newdiv").html(collection[1].Titre.href)   The href is on the Titre object

Comment: My mistake, didn't read properly :) Try this
$(".newdiv").html(collection[1].Titre.text + " " + collection[1].Titre.href);

Comment: This will give you a clickable link 
    $(".newdiv").html(collection[1].Titre.text + " <a href=' " + collection[1].Titre.href + "'>" +  collection[1].Titre.href + "</a>");

Comment: Thank you i did it that way : $(".titre-article1").html(" <a href=' " + collection[1].Titre.href + "'>" + collection[1].Titre.text + "</a>") 

It shows a clickable Title, and its working Aswell

Comment: $(".comme1").html(collection[1].comm);  i want to add a space in the HTML  &nbsp; in the HTML doesnt seems to Work i tried to add it in the Jquery 

$(".comme1").html(" " + collection[1].comm); Its not working neither do i need to Append it or does .html() have a trick ?